# How to add default behavior to @KafkaListener

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I would like to add custom behavior before my method annoted with @KafkaListener is called.

Actually I'm using an abstract class and the final class is using

```
@KafkaListener(topics = ....)
public void onMessages(List<ConsumerRecord> records) {
  super.onMessages(records);
}

@Override
public void process(ConsumerRecord record) {
  // Called by abstract class to really process the message (one by one)
}
```

But I also need to configure the abstract class in a @PostConstruct.

What would be the best approach ?

I would prefer just decorate the default container and use it with something like that :

```
@MyCustomKafkaLister(topics = ....)
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord record) {
  // Just handle the message
}
```

Or by customizing the MessageListenerFactory to create a CustomMessageListener inherited from the default one which will call my method annoted by @KafkaListener after some custom behavior.

But I don't know how.

**Edit 1**

I want my abstract processing to do the following :

```
    public void process(List<ConsumerRecord> records) {
        for (ConsumerRecord<K, V> record : records) {
            // Check message
            try {
                if (record.value() == null) {
                    checkDeser(record, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER);
                }
                if (record.key() == null) {
                    checkDeser(record, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.KEY_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER);
                }
            } catch (DeserializationException ex) {
                this.deadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(record, ex);
                LOGGER.error("Deserialization error recovered to DLT.", ex);
            }

            // Process message
            try {
                // Here I'm calling the original @KafkaListener aka the subclass
                myRealListenerObject.processOneByOne(record);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOGGER.warn("Exception while processing record. Key : {}", record.key(), ex);
                handleException(record, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is calling "myRealListenerObject.processOneByOne(record);" which should be my listener implementation using @KafkaListener (or @CustomKafkaListener)

**Edit 2**

I would like my listeners to be like

```
@CustomKafkaListeners(topics = "myTopic", ...)
public void process(ConsumerRecord record) {
  // Do my stuff
}
```

rather than having something like that for every listeners :

```
@KafkaListeners(topics = "myTopic", ...)
public void process(List<ConsumerRecord> records) {
  for (ConsumerRecord record : records) {
    try {
        if (record.value() == null) {
            checkDeser(record, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER);
        }
        if (record.key() == null) {
            checkDeser(record, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.KEY_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER);
        }
    } catch (DeserializationException ex) {
        this.deadLetterPublishingRecoverer.accept(record, ex);
        LOGGER.error("Deserialization error recovered to DLT.", ex);
    }

    // Process message
    try {
        // Do my stuff
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.warn("Exception while processing record. Key : {}", record.key(), ex);
        MyExceptionHandler.handleException(record, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't have a `@KafkaListener` method on the super class and call some overloaded in the inheritors? This way you can have in the super a common logic and then delegate to the polymorphism.

Comment: I want the super class to be generic and be called by several listeners.
Having @KafkaListener on the superclass prevents me from customizing topics and such

Comment: Exactly what pre-processing do you want to do? Kafka provides a `ConsumerInterceptor` which would allow you to modify the `ConsumerRecord`s before they even reach the container.

Comment: @GaryRussell editer my question

Answer (score 1):

You can perform that logic using a `FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter` with a custom `RecordFilterStrategy` to check for the deserialization exceptions.

Simply add the adapter to the listener container factory.

Comment: I don't really understand. I'm not trying to filter here. I kinda want to reproduce a single record consumer but backed with a BatchListener for performances. Due to the fact that I am using the BatchListener I want each record to have its ErrorHandler that's why I want an abstract which will just read all messages in the batch and process them one by one with a generic (but custom) error handling for each messages. The final listener should not know about this and just process a single record.

Comment: I am not sure why you wouldn't want to filter out the records that failed deserialization but, in any case, you don't **have** to filter, it is just that the `RecordFilterStrategy` is called for each record so you can do what you want there; always returning false will filter no records.

Comment: Its not that I don't want to filter them, but I want them to be sent to a DLT. I still don't understand how am I supposed to send message one by one to my listener using this.

Comment: You can add your logic (checking for deserialization exceptions and sending to a DTL) in the filter strategy.

Comment: What about the try/catch under "// Process message" in my code sample ? I want the catch to be generic but the process to be impl by each listeners

Comment: Why are you even using a batch listener if you only want to process the records one-at-a-time? Just use a normal record listener and a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` configured with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.

Comment: For performance issues using transaction. Consuming records one-at-a-time with transactions is killing my performances, so I want to process them in batch in a single transaction but my process can only handle one message at a time.

Comment: Edited again my question.

Comment: Ah - got it; we don't currently have a solution for that use case; you could write your own infrastructure to do that, but it would be a lot of work and if you are not extremely familiar with Spring internals, not something I would advise taking on; it would be a lot easier for the framework to provide something. As a work-around, I suggest you do the debatching in each listener and open a [new feature issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues) and I'll take a look.